# How to Process Events from now() to -10 minutes in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to create a Stream Flink app that will process the events that falls within the latest event timestamp to different time windows, e.g. 10 minutes, 1 day and 1 month.

So lets say I got an event at 12:01, this is my latest timestamp, so the process will grab all events produced from 12:01 to 12:11. Same for other window sizes.

I am not sure I understand how windows work, but I get that I have a stream and that events will be processed in a window, but there are multiple outputs for a window, and windows have a defined start and end, not a moving start-end timestamp. I guess this would look like a sliding window, where the stream is a fixed size by timestamps, so new events pop out old events as they come if they are out of the 10 minute window.

Is this something I set up in flink or in my datastream (maybe kafka)?

I am relatively new to Flink, and I checked the sliding window documentation, but it seems it serves a different function.

Answer (score 0):

An OVER window might be what you're looking for. For example,

```sql
SELECT order_id, order_time, amount,
  SUM(amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY product
    ORDER BY order_time
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '10' MINUTE PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS ten_minute_prod_amount_sum
FROM Orders
```

computes for every order the sum of amounts of all orders for the same product during the 10 minute period before the current order.

The documentation for OVER windows is [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/over-agg/#over-aggregation).

If you really need to look forward in time, rather than backwards, I'm sorry to say that Flink's OVER windows only support `PRECEDING` and not `FOLLOWING`, but you could build a solution using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. The docs for pattern matching with MATCH_RECOGNIZE are [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/match_recognize/).

I imagine you were looking for a solution using the DataStream API. None of the DataStream window functions handle this use case. You'll either need to go up the API stack to the Table/SQL API, or go down a level and build a solution using process functions.

Comment: I will check the OVER windows, thanks for the tip.
The idea is to get all messages sent last 10 minutes and analyze that data. this will be trigger or be aggregated any new message. Kind of like a FIFO queue.

Comment: If you need to do custom processing, perhaps a user defined aggregation function would do trick. If not, then you'll have to do this with a KeyedProcessFunction rather than SQL.